# Using The Assembly Plugin for Maven and remove the assembly descriptor id from the file name

Tags: maven, zip, maven-2, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I am using the maven plugin

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                    <finalName>calzada-${pom.version}</finalName>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

this is my assembly.xml

```
<assembly
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>id</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
```

but when I compress the file the -id is added at the end of the name file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `appendAssemblyId`:

```xml
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                    <finalName>calzada-${pom.version}</finalName>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId> 
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```